# Yammer embedded Object.Keys: argument is not an object

Tags: sharepoint, office365, yammer

I try to implement Yammer embedded in Office 365(SharePoint Online). I added this code:

```
yam.connect.embedFeed({
                        "container": "#embedded-feed",
                        "network": "*",
                        "feedType": "open-graph",
                        "config": {
                            promptText: "test",
                            use_sso: true,
                            showOpenGraphPreview: false,
                            header: false,
                            footer: false,
                            defaultToCanonical: false
                        },
                        objectProperties:
                            {
                                url: window.location.href,
                                title: document.title,
                                image: "/Style Library/graphics/content/logo.svg",
                                type: "page"
                            }
                    });
```

The code works in chrome but in Internet Explorer 10 and 11 it won't the same issue happends with there configurator

https://www.yammer.com/widget/configure

Is there a workaround:)

Answer (score 1):

Ok in my case what was causing the problem was the network. The network name wasn't correct

How to get the correct network name:

```
1. Go tohttps://www.yammer.com/office365/admin
2. In the menu go to Configuration
3. Under General you find Network name.
```